# Find and replace or remove tags Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to automate removal tags in PDF document structure (container "Artifact", container "Figure"  and etc.)

Cannot find anything related to tags in operation wizard.

I mean tags that appear in content of document

[image]

or what program can work with these tags?

...find and replace or remove

i need this to batch process the file

Comment: I thought it could be solved with VBS scripts?

Comment: i would be very grateful if someone showed me an example of most primitive script for finding and removing a tag for example "span" if it contains a symbol "?". this will help me understand syntax